# GIT pull doesn't pull (EGIT on Spring Tool Suite)

Tags: git, fetch, egit, pull

On **computer A** I created a project and then i pushed it on GitHub.

On **computer B** I imported that project in Spring tool suite.

On **Computer A** I created a class called Base3, I committed It and then I pushed it to GitHub (as you can see from the images below)

[image]
[image]
I'm trying to pull from **computer b**, in order to get the updated version of the project, that include  Base3.java. When I did it, I get the message below
[image]

My **Master** branch configuration seems to be ok.
[image]

Why GIT doesn't pull Base3.java to **computer b**?
I think I'm not clearly undestanding the way GIT works.

Comment: Are you sure Base3.class is included in the commit? you can view the changes on github. It is quite possible that you have a `.gitignore`(possibly created by your tooling) file which specifies `.class` files should be excluded since they are compiled `.java` files, which are likely not ignored.

Comment: Hi @ikkentim, actually what I need is Base3.java. I edited my post and added an image that show that Base3.java is on the repository.

Comment: Does the commit show up in the log on "computer b" ?

Comment: I found the error, was an error of mine. On compyter B I accidentally revert the pull that previously pulled Base2.java. GIT seems to work properly. 
Sorry for making you to waste you time. Thank you